# Controller.Redirect(returnUrl) method checks return url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to redirect users to url where user was before he or she logins.

I have got this code from some open source but I don't understand condition part of if statement described below.

What is exactly LocalUrl?

Why should I check if the "returnUrl" is local or not?

Is LocalUrl anything to do with Absolute url or Relative url?

```
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.islocalurl(v=vs.118).aspx and https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/preventing-open-redirection-attacks explains why IsLocalUrl is useful.

Answer (score 0):

The IsLocalUrl call is there to validate that the return URL is not on some random external site, but belongs to your local site.

This is an approach to guard against Open Redirection Attacks (see [MSDN ref](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/preventing-open-redirection-attacks))

If someone crafted a malicious link with a return URL to a dodgy third party site, this check prevents someone actually being redirected to that site.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, can I ask one more question?

Comment: why should I use the rest conditions after IsLocalUrl() when IsLocalUrl() seems to check the rest conditions itself?

Comment: except the returnUrl.length > 1 condition

Comment: This could be for legacy reasons that are no longer valid - e.g. before IsLocalUrl came along, the  other checks were relevant. If you supply a url starting with e.g. "//", then IsLocalUrl returns false so like you say, it handles that scenario. Checking OWASP, the example there only has the IsLocalUrl call: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/.NET_Security_Cheat_Sheet